# How to disable a div code behind in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a div which I call from code behind via `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`
Another div is inside this div with `style="display: none;` Is it possible to enable the second div when I call the main div in code behind?

This is my code- 
`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenNewWindow", "<script type='text/javascript'>$(function() { $('#MainDiv').dialog('open'); })</script>");`

Comment: if you can call the first one then why not the second one??

Comment: second one is inside the first one and i need to call the second one along with the first one with style changed to `display:block`

Comment: So why is that not happening??? say `$('#MainDiv > :first-child').show();`

Comment: Why don't you use the open event for the dialog to show the inner div?

Comment: @Pitchai Pazhani- I can open the inner div, but how can I change the style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called the class name of second div  like this-

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenNewWindow", "<script type='text/javascript'>$(function() { $('#MainDiv').dialog('open'); });$('.second-div-class').show();</script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
put these attributes in div runat="server"  and an id="a_name"
Declare Your div like following

<div runat="server" id="dv">
your contents
</div>

call the dv from Code behind and then do with that dv whatever you want
```